# how to add cout<<%cursor%<<endl;

Tags: code-snippets, geany

I tried opening Tools-> configuration file -> snippets.conf
and edited [c++] block

```
#~ [C++]
#~ cout=cout<<%cursor%<<endl;
#~ if=if (%cursor%)%block_cursor%
#~ else=else%block_cursor%
#~ for=for (int i = 0; i < %cursor%; i++)%brace_open%\n%brace_close%
#~ while=while (%cursor%)%block_cursor%
#~ do=do\n{\n\t%cursor%\n} while (%cursor%)\n
#~ switch=switch (%cursor%)%brace_open%case %cursor%:\n\t\t%cursor%\n\t\tbreak;\n\tdefault:\n\t\t%cursor%\n%brace_close%
#~ try=try%block%\ncatch (%cursor%)%block_curso
```

I added line`#~ cout=cout<<(cursor%)<<endl;`
then restarted my computer and geany multiple times it neither gave me error nor gave extension in FileName.cpp . When i type cout it gave normal tab not extension i added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fiddling with `snippet.conf` for a half hour or so, I stumbled on the rather annoying answer...

The `#` characters at the beginning of lines in `snippet.conf` are comment characters, and the `~` characters are apparently just there to confuse everybody. So for a snippet to work, both the section heading (e.g. `[C++]`) and the snippet definition should be flush left *without* the leading `#~`. Leading spaces work, but in that case syntax highlighting of the line in `snippet.conf` won't be shown, so it's best to just make things flush left.

Also, after adding a new snippet, there's no need to restart either your computer, geany, or even the document you want to use it in. A new snippet should be available as soon as `snippet.conf` is saved.

And what about all of the commented-out lines in `snippet.conf`? They apparently don't do anything as they are. However, they *can* be used to override geany's default snippet functionality by removing the `#~`  characters from the appropriate section heading and snippet lines and then making changes as needed.

Comment: I just removed #~  and a space it worked.thank you